# UIcollectionviewcell inside UItableviewcell get selection cell index of both ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uitableview

How to get index of cell selected in both `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`?

I have implemented a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a custom UITableViewCell class that is the delegate of your UICollectionView. Then make a property like "selectedCellIndexPath" in the custom UITableViewCell's header and update the property when the didSelect method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Place each custom cell of tableview under separate section. Assign this section index to collection view cell by creating a reference element such as cell tag. Use section tag and collection view cell index to refer individual cells separately. If needed create a delegate method in custom cell class that calls section of section in tableview.